# Migration from AWS ELB to API Gateway over EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, aws-elb

I would like to migrate from AWS ELB to API Gateway with an AWS EKS Cluster.
Reasons: Cost savings, the number of requests is not too large, lower latency, caching, and other things. One problem: I will need to keep both running for while.

That's the scenario:

[image]

I tried to use a private NLB with a VPC Link to access EKS Services that's ok, however, AFAIK I would need one NLB per service, and I have more or less 15 services, which would increase the cost a lot. So, I would like to have a suggestion to connect the API gateway to EKS services, that's cost-effective and have a better performance than ELB, I heard things like use another ingress as an entry point but not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should opt for this

```
User -> API Gateway -> Private Link -> VPC Endpoint
```

Inside VPC, EKS could be configured with Horizontal Node scaler(handle scaling of the system), or Karpenter ([karpenter.sh](https://karpenter.sh/))

Comment: How should I create a VPC endpoint? is that something that points to node manager or ec2 instances?

Comment: @RicardoCunha https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html